# Most direct way to multiply a tuple of ints by a float and get back a tuple of ints

Tags: python, python-2.7, types, tuples

Here's what I'm doing to rescale a tuple of ints to another tuple of ints. Is there a better way?

```
size_tup = tuple([int(round(s*shrink)) for s in size])
```

I need this for an image resize with the `Image` module, as that requires a `tuple` of `ints`. So for example, if I want to resize an image by 50% I would do

```
size = .5     
size_tup = tuple([int(round(s*shrink)) for s in size])   
im = im.resize(size_tup, Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

So I'm only working with a tuple of length 2. I'm mostly concerned with simplicity of the code as the above seems like overkill.

Comment: This question would be much better with some example data and desired output

Comment: @bebop I added more details per your comment.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are creating a list and then converting it to a tuple. Use the [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function to delay evaluation of of the list (in python3) instead.

```
size_tup = tuple(
            map(int, #this function calls int on each element
                map(round, #this function calls round on each element
                    map(lambda x : x * shrink, #this function multplies each element by shrink
                        size))))
```

Based  on the comment, you can do this too (remove `[]`):

```
tuple(int(round(s*shrink)) for s in size)
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I am not sure this is any simpler than what I propose above. I think I can replace my brackers with a generator expression in any case, no? That will eliminate the creation of the list, but I'm only working with a small list anyway.

Comment: see the edit. I don't quite understand what you mean by "simpler". You generally use map function to apply something to all elements in a given iterable.

Comment: I'll upvote for the last suggestion, using a generator expression rather than a list comprehension inside the `tuple` call. Python doesn't really need `map`, though it can be nice when you have exactly one pre-written function to apply. If you're chaining map calls together or using a `lambda` function you probably shouldn't bother.

Answer (score -1):

I think something similar to this would help you.

```
map(lambda x: x * n, tuple)
```

As per definition of the map function:

> `map(function, iterable, ...)`
>   Apply function to every item of iterable and return a list of the results